# Karate; Object type not being throws TypeError as "not an Object"

Tags: automation, karate

With my testing I am looking to do some evaluating on json objects within an array.  The example looks like this:

```
"sections": [
  {
    "internal_id": 10635,
    "uuid": "a56357fa-fbe6-BARS-89d4-8e8fdbda18b0",
  },
  {
    "internal_id": 10636,
    "uuid": "33a4c634-BARS-4b20-ac3d-54370b32d989",
  },
  {
    "internal_id": 10637,
    "uuid": "99443ce8-5007-4ec2-BARS-b459df30d33b",
  },
  {
    "internal_id": 10638,
    "uuid": "4a54a868-1bfa-BAZZ-93b1-d95a4b529cdf",
  }
]
```

While doing some debugging I did this:

`* print typeof(sections[0])` => this comes back saying `object`

I have tried to evaluate individual objects doing this:

`* eval Object.keys(sections[0]).length;` => this comes back with `TypeError: <object_at_index_0> is not an Object in <eval>`

I don't have a lot of experience with JS, but could someone help me out with this?

Comment: what do you want to validate from this JSON Array ??

Comment: @BabuSekaran all yours :)

Comment: @BabuSekaran, I would like to validate that the length of the object is 2.  Or, basically validate that each object within the JSON array is the same size.  In my debugging before writing out an assertion, this threw me as to why I couldn't evaluate the object even though the type was listed as an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an expected schema for a single JSON object and then use `match each` to validate it for all the data in the JSON Array.

```
* def sectionArray =
"""
{
"sections": [
  {
    "internal_id": 10635,
    "uuid": "a56357fa-fbe6-BARS-89d4-8e8fdbda18b0",
  },
  {
    "internal_id": 10636,
    "uuid": "33a4c634-BARS-4b20-ac3d-54370b32d989",
  },
  {
    "internal_id": 10637,
    "uuid": "99443ce8-5007-4ec2-BARS-b459df30d33b",
  },
  {
    "internal_id": 10638,
    "uuid": "4a54a868-1bfa-BAZZ-93b1-d95a4b529cdf",
  }
]
}
"""
* match each sectionArray.sections == {"internal_id":"#present","uuid":"#present"}
```

You can also validate the size of the array by,

```
* match sectionArray.sections == "#[4]"
```

Refer [Fuzzy Matching](https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching)

Comment: Okay, so, as I understand it, by doing a match for `"#present"` on both keys, this asserts that it will fail if there is ONE key or if there are > 2 keys per object?

Comment: Each JSON object should exactly have only `internal_id` and `uuid` key, any other case would fail.